# How to input a variable with XML to validate against XSD

Tags: java, javascript, xml, xsd, jaxp

I have this code to make a validation of a XML file with a XSD. And this code works!

```
var schemaFile = new Packages.java.io.File("C:\\schema.xsd");
var url = new Packages.java.net.URL("file:C:\\input.xml");
var xmlFile = new Packages.javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(url);
var schemaFactory = Packages.javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
var schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);

var validator = schema.newValidator();

try {
    validator.validate(xmlFile);
    logger.info('valid');
} catch (err) {
    logger.error(err.toString());
}
```

But now, instead of using a XML file as input in here

```
var xmlFile = new Packages.javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(url);
```

I want to use a variable, passed before, that has a XML in it. If I write the variable there

```
var xmlFile = new Packages.javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(msg);
```

I get an error protocol

```
JavaException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
```

This is because StreamSource needs a specified protocol, for a File it was easy (file:path). How can I put there a variable instead of a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource` can be constructed from a URL or a InputStream or a Reader. If the `msg` is your xml. Create a StringReader using that string and instantiate the `StreamSource` with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`SAXSource` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/sax/SAXSource.html), which has a constructor that takes an [`InputSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) argument.

There's an `InputSource` constructor that takes a [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html#InputSource%28java.io.Reader%29) argument, so you can use that constructor and use the [`StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) implementation.

In code:

```
var reader = new Packages.java.io.StringReader(msg);
var source = new Packages.org.xml.sax.InputSource(reader);
var xmlFile = new Packages.javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource(source);
```